# Помощь с html плеером

Tags: html, css, видео

Здравствуйте, не подскажите как можно сделать одинаковый дизайн (или хотя бы немного похожий) стандартного видео плеера на всех браузерах (а точнее на Chrome и на Internt Explorer) спасибо.

p.s Забыл уточнить, я использую стандартный плеер `<video></video>`

Comment: Берёшь и создаёшь :) По-моему, гениально

Answer (score 0):

Минимальный ответ для "немного похожего" дизайна.

```
<video width="400" controls>
  <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Беда! Браузер не поддерживает HTML5 видео :)
</video>
```